# The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive types

Tags: mysql, linq, executestorequery

I am trying to delete multiple rows from the table using linq's `ExecuteStoreQuery` method like this

```
 string query = "delete from IMPORTStatistics where districtid='" + districtId + "'";
 db.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(query);
```

but it is throwing this exception

```
"The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive types."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just for the information, I am using MySql.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) can't wait for you to release your code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you're executing a delete command (not a query), I think you should be using [`ExecuteStoreCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) instead of `ExecuteStoreQuery`.

Additionally, you should *definitely* be using parameters instead of putting the ID directly into the command.

```
string command = "delete from IMPORTStatistics where districtid={0}";
int rowsDeleted = db.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, districtId);
```

Comment: So the parameter would be in paranthesis {0} and not in general syntax of database variables like @DistrictId?

Comment: @PawanNogariya: That's a wider discussion - if you look into Entity Framework in more detail, I believe both are valid, but possibly in different contexts. (e.g. depending on whether you provide `SqlParameter`s or just the values.)

Comment: hmm.. ok. Then I should go in entity framework detail a little :) Thanks!

Comment: Then, how can we catch the result of the query?  I run a stored proc through ExecuteStoreCommand but the result is -1 regardless of what the stored proc returns.  And if I try using ExecuteStoreQuery, I get this same error.

Comment: @MathieuLeblanc: Well what is your stored proc doing? It sounds like it may be worth asking a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. In the end, I solved it with a hack : I modified the SP to not only return an integer, but also Select it, so I can grab the result with an ExecuteStoreQuery<int>. Thanks for your reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is really helpful link after goggling I found this

http://welcometoaspdotnet.blogspot.com/2012/08/execute-stored-procedure-with-entity.html

thx